# What does vector.back().back() return?

Tags: c++, vector

Suppose I have `vector<string> v`

What does  `v.back().back()` return?

Does it return the last string of the last string of the vector?

It is same as `v.end().end()` ?

Comment: A vector of what? `vector` is a generic library in C++ and needs a type parameter.

Comment: did you read any documentation before asking here? If you read something you didn't understand please tell us

Comment: `.end()` is an iterator that points *past* the last element *not* to the last element, so no it cannot be the same as back(). Dereferencing .end() is UB, .back() returns a valid element (as long as size > 0 ofc)

Comment: A string contains characters, not strings.

Comment: Did you do some research about [std::vector::back()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back), [std::vector::end()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end), [std::string::back()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/back) and [std::string::end()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/end)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`v.back().back()` is equivalent to `( v.back() ).back()`.

- for a nonempty vector `v`, `v.back()` is the last element of `v`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/back/
- for a nonempty string `s`, `s.back()` is the last character of `s`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/back/

If `v` is vector of strings, then `v.back().back()` is the last character of the last string of `v`.

If `v` is empty or the last string of `v` is empty, then `v.back().back()` causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: thanks @idclev463035818, I edited to take your comment into account